# R or Excel: Calculate difference between dates

Tags: r, excel, differences

I have a list of course completion dates (person, start, end) in the following format (exemplary):

Person X || Sept 21, 2021 06:30 PM || Sept 21, 2021 06:50 PM

Now I'd like to calculate the overall spent time in minutes from the difference between end and start date. However, I struggle with formatting the start and end date in a way that allows such difference calculations. Excel does not seem to provide a date format that suits the given table record. Manual formatting would take ages since the table is pretty long.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance